# Error: An unsupported media type was attempted to be imported as a module

Tags: import, media, deno

This is my `deps.ts` file:

deps.ts:

```
export {
  Application,
  Router,
  Context,
  send,
} from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v9.0.1/mod.ts";
export type { RouterContext } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v9.0.1/mod.ts";
export { MongoClient } from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.27.0/mod.ts";
export {
  hashSync,
  compareSync,
} from "https://deno.land/x/bcrypt@v0.2.4/mod.ts";
import "https://deno.land/x/dotenv@v3.0.0/load.ts";
export { create, verify, decode, getNumericDate,  }  from "https://deno.land/x/djwt@v2.4/mod.ts";
```

And this is a part of code that I think the error comes from:

auth_controller.ts:

```
import {
  create, verify, decode, getNumericDate, RouterContext, hashSync, compareSync
} from "../deps.ts";
import { userCollection } from "../mongo.ts";
import User from "../models/user.ts";
```

This is the error message I receive:

> error: An unsupported media type was attempted to be imported as a
> module.   Specifier:
> file:///C:/NewP/app_back/controllers/auth_controller   MediaType:
> Unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in one of the other application files I had imported `auth_controller` file with no `.ts` extension. I added the `.ts` extension in the end of that import line and the problem resolved.